# What does the operator </> do in FAKE build scripts?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I just found this target in a FAKE build script generated by ProjectScaffold:

```
// Copies binaries from default VS location to expected bin folder
// But keeps a subdirectory structure for each project in the
// src folder to support multiple project outputs
Target "CopyBinaries" (fun _ ->
    !! "src/**/*.??proj"
    -- "src/**/*.shproj"
    |>  Seq.map (fun f -> ((System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName f) 
            </> "bin/Release", "bin" 
            </> (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension f)))
    |>  Seq.iter (fun (fromDir, toDir) -> CopyDir toDir fromDir (fun _ -> true))
)
```

My question: What does this strange `</>` operator do?

(My internet search was not very successful.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The operator `</>` is an infix operator and combines two path segments into one complete path. In this aspect it is almost the same as the @@ operator. The `</>` operator was created after the @@ operator because the @@ operator behaves strangely on UNIX-like systems when the second path starts with root.

Here is an example taken from the issue description on GitHub.

```
    "src" @@ "/home/projects/something" returns "src/home/projects/something"

    "src" </> "/home/projects/something" returns "/home/projects/something"
```

The operator  is defined in EnvironmentHelper:
https://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-environmenthelper.html

These links points to the problem description:
https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/670, 
https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/pull/695

Comment: To my eyes (used to looking at Unix), the @@ operator is totally normal and does exactly what you would expect it to do.  And </> is just deeply strange.